# Add a where clause on ecto assoc join table

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have three models `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table1to2`. `Table1to2` is a join table from Table1 to Table2, with the schema of Table1 and Table2 being:

```
schema "table1" do
  many_to_many :table2, Table2, join_through: Table1to2
end 

schema "table2" do
  many_to_many :table1, Table1, join_through: Table1to2
end
```

The key thing is that my join table, `Table1to2` has a column/field which I need to query against. Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
Repo.get!(Table1, id) |> Repo.preload(table2: (from j in Table1to2, where: [main: true]))
```

This understandably does not work because there is no direct defined association from Table1 to Table1to2. Doing this however:

```
Repo.get!(Table1, id) |> Repo.preload(table2: (from j in Table2, where: [main: true]))
```

results in this query:

```
from p0 in Table1,
  join: u in Table1to2,
  on: u.table1_id == p0.id,
  join: p1 in Table2,
  on: u.table2_id == p1.id,
  where: p1.main == true,        #should be u.main == true
  where: p0.id == ^"2",
  select: p0,
  preload: [table_2: p1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the query syntax like the resulting query you posted to fit your needs.

```
query = 
  from t1 in Table1,
  join: t12 in Table1to2, on: t12.table1_id == t1.id,
  join: t2 in Table2, on: t12.table2_id == t2.id,
  where: t12.main == :true and t1.id == ^table1_id,
  preload: [table2: t1],
  select: t1

result = Repo.one(query)
```

Comment: True, and that's what I'm currently doing in the moment. It'd be great if there's a way to do this without explicit queries though, as it's a PITA when I have to preload/chain other queries. Ecto supports custom HABTM models too which makes me feel there should be a way to do this cleanly.